# Laravel - Sort results by file size

Tags: laravel

I want create a function that will sort the entries by their file size from a table called assets.

```
public function getAssetOrderBySize() {
    $current_user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $query = DB::table('assets')->where('uploader_id', '=', $current_user_id)->orderBy('id', 'size');

    return View::make('file.library', compact('query'));
}
```

The above function doesn't seem to return the files in the order I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is you are sorting by id and that's not making a lot of sense.

Also, the correct syntax is `orderBy($column, $direction)` so what you should be doing is `->orderBy('size', 'asc')` or `->orderBy('size', 'desc')` depending on which direction you want them.